# gdbserver and ymm0h register

Tags: debugging, cpu-registers, gdbserver

Does anyone know what on earth is a `ymm0h` register in the context of gdbserver (see: https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/i386-Features.html)? I know what ymm0 is but what is this 'h' that's tagging along? There is expectedly no `xmm0h` register.

The background is I am trying to experiment with remote debugging and every time a connection is made with gdbserver it always fails with:

```
../../gdbserver/regcache.cc:271: A problem internal to GDBserver has been detected.
Unknown register ymm0h requested
```

Other hits for this problem suggest upgrading gdbserver to 8.0+ but I am running v14.1. So that doesn't seem to be it.

gdbserver itself is running on a Linux machine RH 8.6 (Intel Xeon Gold 6240) and the connection is being made from a debugger on a Windows machine which is capable of connecting to gdbserver.

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to be the upper 128 bits of the 256 bit register, but that explains nothing about why this is going wrong

Comment: precisely. I have now debugged gdbserver itself and I can see the codepath it takes. I just don't understand why it complains if the connection is attempted from a Windows. It has no issues if the same connection is being established by another Linux machine.

Comment: @harold BTW, thanks! I now understand ymm0h is upper 128 bits of ymm0. 'h' being 'high' I guess. I wish they had `ymm0l` (like `al`, `bl` etc) instead. It was so confusing.

Comment: I suppose `ymm0h` etc were defined because there was already a name for the lower half (namely `xmm0`) but the upper half is not directly accessible and has no official name